# What is the history of the set numbers of Lego sets through time?

Tags: set-identification, history, set-database

I was wondering how Lego went from a 4 digit code to a complete family and set of products to identify them like the Creator set, the System set...

Of course part of it is their growth but does anyone have more information on how the product code changed throughout the years?

Answer (score 4):

There is nice article on Brickset called "[The history of 5-digit set numbers](https://brickset.com/article/54434/the-history-of-5-digit-set-numbers)". While this article is not a historic information on transformation it is still quite interesting read since it is based on data collected by the website itself.